# Is the Raspberry pi the best choice for my 24V compressor IoT project?

Tags: pi-2, rpi.gpio, arduino

I am building and outdoor IoT refrigerated mailbox with a DC 24V compressor with few sensors like (temp, approximately, LED lights, LED Screen). I'll be controlling the 24VDC compressor power supply on-off based on the desired temperature.

I'm planning to connect the pi to IBM Watson Bluemix to push/get json.

Is the raspberry pi suitable for such project, with a continuously running 24/7? what issues that I might face? Any recommendations?

Would you say that the Arduino boards is a safer options to such projects?

Comment: Welcome to Raspberry Pi! Please take the [tour](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/tour) and visit the [helpcenter](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help) to see how things work here. If the Arduino can handle the work load (which I expect it would), you can program it (or are willing to learn) it is certainly an alternative - an using less electricity. Other than that Pi's are reported to work for 700+ days (just checking my datalogging system, uptime 588 days), see the linked question.